# Error while installing blackberry plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I want to add the blackberry plugins in eclipse.I am using the link: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/3.6/web/

but I am getting following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found
Software being installed: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 
    (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using eclipse update site?

Comment: @Mister Smith The URL that is pointed to is a valid Eclipse update site.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can add JRE when you already had the plugin. You can try that and see if the plug in is listed there:

Name: BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site

URL: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java

Or you can download Eclipse + Plugin from here:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp